# Replace thousand number with 0 on an integer

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I need an easy solution, in javascript, to remove thousands from an integer

for example:

```
29492 => 20492
1024 => 24
12345 => 10345
```

How could i do this easily ? the shorter/clearer the better

Comment: Only ask a question for either JavaScript or Java not both. Create two different questions.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn ok, i will only ask for javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I agree with Get Off My Lawn, you could have a solution that wok for both, with simple use of modulo.

```
x = x - (x%10000) + (x%1000)
//29492 => 29492 - 9492 + 492
```